# Any examples of Monte-Carlo analysis in R for sample size calculations for SEM?

Tags: r, monte-carlo, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I would like to calculate required sample size for my SEM model to achieve the power of at least 0.8.

I read some articles that recommend using Monte-Carlo analysis in order to determine the sample size for the specific model, however cannot find any clear examples of the implementation in R. Ideally, I would like an example considering non-normal data distribution.

Any suggestions on where to find more information on this?

Comment: You can take a look at these packages in R: (1) https://simsem.org/ (2) https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/semPower/vignettes/semPower.pdf Also, if you have access to Mplus there's a command for power analysis.

Comment: Many thanks, simsem package seems to have everything I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

[This Github page](http://github.com/simsem/simsem/wiki/Vignette) provides a number of R-based simulation examples for structural equation modeling (sem).

If you are asking for Power Analysis in Model Evaluation, then the syntax is [here](http://github.com/simsem/simsem/wiki/Example-6:-Power-Analysis-in-Model-Evaluation-%28Version-0.2%29). However, if you are asking for Power to detect target parameters, then use [this syntax](http://github.com/simsem/simsem/wiki/Example-20:-Simulation-with-Varying-Sample-Size-and-Parameters).

Furthermore, one of the benefits of the aforementioned github page is that it provides sem codes from popular sem packages, such as `Lavaan`, `simsem`, and `OpenMx`. So there are so many useful things for you to discover here. Personally, I found this page extremely useful for getting your head around sem simulations.